# Java, using wait and notify properly to pause thread execution from another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have an issue trying to pause a threads execution from another thread. I have read the java docs and a few stack-overflow examples and still seem to be a little lost.

Many cases are just like mine; I have a gui that spawns a thread to do some work so it can stay responsive to the user. At some point the user does something that makes it desirable to just stop the worker thread before it executes its next statement. And then after sometime, continue its work.

I have read the `wait` and `notify` documentation for `Threads`, and this seems to be the short answer to the question above(?).

And from what my IDE (netbeans) tells me, I must call `wait` and `notify` inside a synchronized block.

So here is what I had in my JFrame for when my start pause button was pressed. `automator` is my `Thread` object that I want paused. Its declared as `static final` in my JFrame. `firstRunDone` is just a flag for the first time the `m_jbStartPause` is pressed, so the `automator` can be started and not notified.

```
OnStartPauseButton()
{
    synchronized(automator)
    {
         if(!running)
         {
              this.m_jbStartPause.setText("Pause");
              running = true;
              if(firstRunDone)
                  automator.notify();
              else
                  automator.start();
              firstRunDone = true;
         }
         else 
         {
             this.m_jbStartPause.setText("Start");
             running = false;
             try { automator.wait(); }  catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
         }
    }
}
```

My problem is with when I first try to pause the thread. I can hit start and the automator starts, but when I hit pause all that happens is the JFrame freezes and the automator continues doing its work.

Am i using syncronized wrong? Does `automator` need any handling code?

Comment: You're blocking on the GUI event thread...

Comment: Yes, `automator` needs handling code, because it is the party that has to invoke `wait` for this to work. If you could post some minimal code from automator, this would help to find an answer.

Comment: Please have a look at [StartStopPauseThread.java](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5021rcrhw3ewngd/StartStopPauseThread.java), hopefully this might be able to give you some idea :-)

Answer (score 1):

- you'd better use [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) in order to update UI instead of using your worker thread
- if you need to 'cancel' your thread, you need to make your "running" flag as **volatile**
- instead of using "synchronized", I'd suggest to use [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) and it's conditions

Comment: could you please explain the invokeLater better, how it applies to my situation? I am not sure what you mean by "in order to update UI" ... The second comment I understand. And the third, from what I can read is just `synchronized` but with more options. Though from what I can tell the entire `synchronized` block I use is useless because it causes my UI to wait and not my worker. I think I have to use a crappy solution of placing a flag check after each line in automator to see if it should wait or continue.

Answer (score 1):

FOllowing line is the issue

```
try { automator.wait(); }  catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
```

This will cause the thread (YOUR GUI) thread to wait not the automator. JAVA docs says

> wait()..Causes the current thread to wait until another thread invokes
>   the notify() method or the notifyAll() method for this object, or some
>   other thread interrupts the current thread, or a certain amount of
>   real time has elapsed

That's why your JFrame appears to be frozen and automator keeps running. You need to build a mechanism in automator that polls the status of a flag to see if it needs to continue its work..and your GUI thread should change the status of the flag to stop automator from working.
.

Comment: So if I want automator to stop before it executes another line when paused is pressed, I need to check a flag in the JFrame after each line in automator? So it might look `int i=0; while(mainView.flag) {sleep();} i = 5; while(flag)sleep; ...` there isn't a way for the automator thread to continuously check the flag without writing a line after each line of the current code?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your query..basically, in your case automator would check a flag (defined in automator itself) and proceed..now you can set this flag to true / false from JFrame..This flag needs to be accessed in a thread safe way.(volatile)..another way to do this is to check threads inturrepted status of automator thread..and you can inturrept this thread in JFrane when you need to pause that.

Comment: My issue is I want to check the flag after each step the automator takes. Say the entirety of the worker thread is `run{ while(true){ //step1; //step2; //step3;}}` Say were at step two, and the user hits pause, I want to pause before step three. So must I after each step in my thread check for the flag? Basically put in a flag check after every single line in run? Or is there a trick I can do to keep the code clean? Such as automator.wait and .notify?

Comment: Wait/notofy would not work in this situation (you dont want to block your automator thread)..you can check the flag status at certain time interval or the way you mentioned..or after each step..If your operation is interruptible then you can just interrupt the automator thread